# Count average cost and update cost of all products in column with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

please help me with following:

I have table "Products" and have following task: Count average cost and update cost of all products in column "UnitPrice" with conditions if current price > average then -10% if < +20%

By the way need to use variables

Please help me to write script I use SQL Server 2000

I wrote somthing like that:

```
DECLARE @Average_cost

SELECT @Average_cost = AVG(UnitPrice)  FROM Products  

UPDATE Products
SET UnitPrice = CASE WHEN UnitPrice > @Average_cost 
                      THEN -10% 
                      ELSE UnitPrice < @Average_cost 
                      THEN + 20%
```

Thanks everybody before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Average_cost

SELECT @Average_cost = AVG(UnitPrice)  FROM Products  
UPDATE Products
SET UnitPrice = (CASE WHEN UnitPrice > @Average_cost 
                      THEN UnitPrice - (UnitPrice * .1)
                      WHEN UnitPrice < @Average_cost 
                      THEN UnitPrice + (UnitPrice * .2)  
                      ELSE @Average_cost                   
                END)
```

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Updated my answer. In `CASE` clause, we have to use `WHEN` when we give some condition instead of `ELSE`.

Comment: If `UnitPrice` equals `@Average_cost` this statement will assign `null` to `UnitPrice`.

Comment: And Buddy one little question what does it mean that sign * .2 ? like * 0.2 ?

Comment: Yes. It is 0.2 (20% = 20/100)

Comment: Thank a lot wish you good luck in everything and in everywhere !

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
UPDATE Products
SET UnitPrice = (CASE WHEN UnitPrice > @Average_cost 
                      THEN UnitPrice - UnitPrice/10 
                      WHEN UnitPrice < @Average_cost 
                      THEN UnitPrice + UnitPrice/5                      
                END)
```

Comment: -1 In else, It should be +20%. I think it should be `UnitPrice + UnitPrice/5`?

Comment: It should be like I've described into my post